# Where do matrix A and A transpose come from in calculating the predicted covariance matrix?

Tags: kalman-filter

I don't understand where the matrices `A` and `A transpose` come from in the equation in [this series](https://youtu.be/H7x4yZbgNOk). I have done a one-dimensional example in the series but I don't see how to derive these matrices in matrix form.

[image: Equation image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $A$ matrix (sometimes $F$) comes from your equations of motion. There's a [technical example on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Example_application,_technical) that goes over modeling position and speed of a truck.

You can model speed and position with the following equations:

$$
x = x_0 + \Delta t \dot{x} + \frac{1}{2}\Delta t^2 \ddot{x} \\
\dot{x} = \dot{x}_0 + \Delta t \ddot{x} \\
$$

Assuming your input $u$ is the acceleration ($u = \ddot{x}$), and being more explicit with the coefficients on everything, you could rewrite the above as:

$$
x = \left(1\right)x_0 + \left(\Delta t\right) \dot{x} + \left(\frac{1}{2}\Delta t^2\right) u \\
\dot{x} = \left(0\right)x_0 + \left(1\right)\dot{x}_0 + \left(\Delta t\right)u \\
$$

And then you convert to matrix form:

$$
\left[\begin{matrix}
x \\
\dot{x}\end{matrix}\right] = 
\left[\begin{matrix}
1 & \Delta t \\
0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix}
x_0 \\
\dot{x}_0 \end{matrix}\right] + \left[\begin{matrix}
\frac{1}{2}\Delta t^2 \\
\Delta t\end{matrix}\right]u
$$

The current sample being:
$$
x_k = \left[\begin{matrix}
x \\
\dot{x}\end{matrix}\right]
$$
and the previous sample being:
$$
x_{k-1} = \left[\begin{matrix}
x_0 \\
\dot{x}_0 \end{matrix}\right]
$$

You can then define your "state matrix" $A$ or $F$ as:

$$
A = 
\left[\begin{matrix}
1 & \Delta t \\
0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right]
$$
and your input matrix $B$ or $G$ as:

$$
B = \left[\begin{matrix}
\frac{1}{2}\Delta t^2 \\
\Delta t\end{matrix}\right]
$$

And so you have:

$$
x_k = Ax_{k-1} + Bu
$$

And then those are used with the output equations:

$$
y_k = Cx_k + Du
$$

to form the Kalman filter. These are all standard matrices from the [state space representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-space_representation) of a system.

Comment: To expand on this. The value we are estimating is assumed to be a gaussian distribution with $x - \mathcal{N}(x,P)$. Chuck shows how $A$ works on the mean($x$). In your equation you are estimating the covariance. The transpose is used to keep the matrix symmetric, and because the covariance is the variance^2. You essentially need to square the $A$ matrix. Which is accomplished by multiplying by the transpose. A proof of this can be found here(https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332441/affine-transformation-applied-to-a-multivariate-gaussian-random-variable-what)

Comment: Thanks, @edwinem ! Op's question was about "where the matrices A and A transpose come from" in the equations, so I tried to answer just that aspect as directly as possible, but this is great context and excellent further reading :)

Comment: I needed the math part too.

Comment: @heretoinfinity - What do you mean? You need the math part for what? What is missing from the answer I provided, or what can I explain better?

Comment: The linear algebra and how I ended up with the transpose. I see it in the link with the comment so that's solved.